# gcsfs for google cloud storage throws error

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export google earth engine data to my google cloud storage bucket using a python tool called ml4floods. It uses gcsfs at its backend for this task.

but when I set all necessary environment variables like this

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/omer/sat/application_default_credentials.json"
os.environ["GS_USER_PROJECT"] = "Floods-analysis"
bucket_name = "floodanalysis"
```

and run my code, i get the following error traceback:

```
     25 filename = f"{path_to_export}albania_ts_{date}"
     26 desc=f"albania_ts_{date}"
---> 27 task = ee_download.mayberun(
     28                     filename,
     29                     desc,
     30                     lambda: img_export,
     31                     export_task_fun_img,
     32                     overwrite=False,
     33                     dry_run=False,
     34                     bucket_name=bucket_name,
     35                     verbose=2,
     36                 )
     37 if task is not None:
     38     tasks.append(task)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml4gdal/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ml4floods/data/ee_download.py:299, in mayberun(filename, desc, function, export_task, overwrite, dry_run, verbose, bucket_name)
    296 if bucket_name is not None:
    297     fs = get_filesystem("gs://")
--> 299     files_in_bucket = fs.glob(f'gs://{bucket_name}/{filename}*')
    300     if len(files_in_bucket) > 0:
    301         if overwrite:
...
    948     "should be str, int or float, got {!r} "
    949     "of type {}".format(v, cls)
    950 )

TypeError: Invalid variable type: value should be str, int or float, got None of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

I checked all the system variables, project information and stuff but they alright.

My credentials JSON file is like this:

```
  "client_id": "<removed this>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "<removed this>",
  "quota_project_id": "floods-analysis",
  "refresh_token": "<removed-this>",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

Comment: 1) What are the contents of `application_default_credentials.json`? The `type` key should have the value `service_account`. 2) Is `Floods-analysis` the Project Name or Project ID? You should be using the Project ID. 3) The error is at `files_in_bucket = fs.glob(f'gs://{bucket_name}/{filename}*')`. Since a previous line checks the `bucket_name`, that means the `filename` is suspect. Add a print statement before that line. What is its value? 4) However, I think you have compounding problems starting with invalid credentials.

Comment: 1){
  "client_id": "<removed this>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "<i removed this>",
  "quota_project_id": "floods-analysis",
  "refresh_token": "<removed this>",
  "type": "authorized_user"
} (2) this was the project name, the demo code had the project name so used it, will try after changing it to project-id. (3) filename is set to "albania_ts_20210116". I set it at my end. But even if I set the filename to an empty string, the same error pops up (4) tried with all your changes to credentials' type property and did project name to project id, but error still occurs.

Comment: Add those details to your post nicely formatted and not via comments.

Comment: Note: you need to download a service account JSON file from the Google Console GUI and use that in your code. You are trying to use OAuth Client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As John Hanley commented, I was supplying OAuth Client credentials instead of service account credentials in the environment variable `"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"`.

That was the only issue, and as soon as I fixed it by downloading service account credentials and pointing to it instead, everything became okay.